# how can I show sql result in a different column which have a different id value?

Tags: sql

the problem is this 
if I have a select statement like so

```
select table1.id,table1.name
from table1
inner join table 2
..
where category = 5
and table2.type = 7
and property in (8,9,10)
order by table1
```

how can I separate the rows witch have a different type id?

ids that contain 7 3 9

example:

```
select table1.id,table1.name
from table1
inner join table 2
..
where category = 5
and table2.type = 7
and property in (8,9,10)
order by table1

select table1.id,table1.name
from table1
inner join table2
..
where category = 5
and table2.type = 3
and property = 17
order by table1
```

Then, I want to obtain this:

```
id | name | 7 | 3|
```

I tried to make a copy of the table and tried to access the same id but with a different table name.... it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simply, put the results of each into a temp table, ensuring you have a common link you can join on. Then, just join the temp tables and the results from the first two tables will be in different columns.

```
select table1.id,table1.name
into #temp1
from table1
inner join table 2
..
where category = 5
and table2.type = 7
and property in (8,9,10)
order by table1

select table1.id,table1.name
into #temp2
from table1
inner join table2
..
where category = 5
and table2.type = 3
and property = 17
order by table1

select temp1.id, temp1.name, temp2.id, temp2.name
from #temp1
join #temp2 on temp1.id = temp2.id
```